# Protractor E2E : get first value from getText() method?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing, angularjs-e2e, gulp-protractor

I have element selector which is selected by repeater.
I am getting

```
$186
Cost
```

from

```
element.getText().then(function (balance) {
          console.log(balance);
        });
```

I need to pick only $186, I tried to get by using `first();` of the element.
and balance[0]. But not finding a solution.
Please suggest.

Comment: Can you pass HTML code and how you defined `element`, please?

Comment: This is in repeater class with some lable like
{{amount}} <label>amount</label>

Comment: And both values ($186 and Cost) are in the same tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the elements exist in the DOM like below:

```
<span ng-repeat="record in records">$186</span><span ng-repeat="record in records">Cost</span>
```

Then the following code works:

```
element.all(by.repeater('record in records')).get(0).getText().then(function(txt) {
    console.log('txt:'+txt);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting the text from the element store inside an string.
Find the desired substring as you know the pattern.

```
var res = str.substring(0, 4);//Change as per the pattern or use regex if required.
```